# Google maps doesn't have data connection

Tags: google-maps, data-connection

Ever since upgrading my Nexus 4 to CyanogenMod 10.1-20130304, Google Maps behaves improperly.  I have not noticed the problem with any other app.

I can open the Maps app, and it will show me where I am, but when I try to search, 95%+ of the time, it will just sit there as though it's searching, but it never finds any results.

The only way I have found to resolve the issue is to completely remove the Google Maps app, and re-install it.  Doing this will allow search to work--once.

The next time I need to search again, I have to remove and re-install.

This happens whether using mobile Internet or wifi.

Is there anything I can do short of restoring the phone to factory settings and starting over?

Comment: If you know how to get the log, it would be of some help to compare the entries during first and subsequent search requests.

Comment: @Narayanan: I don't know how to get the log, but if you can point me in the right direction I would be happy to go log-hunting.

Comment: Try Catlog - [Logcat Reader!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5ub2xhbmxhd3Nvbi5sb2djYXQiXQ..). This app helps you take the log and to filter out the entries. You may be able to spot the trouble by seeing the log in the phone or can spot/compare easily if you export and see it in a computer.

Comment: @Narayanan: Thanks for the tip. Installing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I resorted to restoring my phone to factory settings, and now this works again.